# Ajax data embedding page instead of returning proper results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple search area that that uses JavaScript to display relevant search results while the user is typing. The following is the code for it:

```
<div class="message_content">
    <input type="text" id="user_search" class="form-control search_box" placeholder="Search for people">
    <div id="search_results">
        <span class="no-result" style="line-height: 38px;">Enter your query</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following is the JS in `lib.js`:

```
$("input#user_search").keyup(function() {
    var elt = $("input#user_search").val();
    $curr = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url : "u.search.php",
        type: "GET",
        data : {val: elt},
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if (data.length) {
                $("div#search_results").html(data);
            }
            else $("div#search_results").html('<span class=\"no-result\">Enter your query</span>');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}
    });
});
```

Lastly, the following is the code for `u.search.php`:

```
<?php
$search = strtolower(htmlspecialchars($_GET['val']));

if (strlen($search) < 1);else {
    // Run query on the DB
    ...
    print "<div id=\"search-list\" class=\"list-group\">";
    // populate results
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
    {
        // variable declarations
        print "<a href=\"#\" id=\"$result\" class=\"list-group-item\">";
        print     "<img src=\"$pic\">";
        print     "<span>$name</span>";
        print "</a>";
    }
    print "</div>";
}
?>
```

The problem here is that if I type anything in the textbox, the `index.php` page (page where the search box resides), the html of `div#search_results` becomes `index.php`. If I do `console.log(data)` in the ajax `success` function, the console shows the code of the index.php page (not the actual source code, but the one that you can see in the browser's page source).

`div#search_results` basically has index.php embedded inside it. I tried making changes to the PHP backend code, but no changes reflected in the results. What's wrong here?

Comment: Check your server configuration. And please explain how you know it's `index.php`? Also: Have you tried removing `index.php` by deleting it? What does happen then?

Comment: sounds like a redirect is occurring perhaps, such as a 404 redirect to home page. Are you sure the path is valid? Are you using a server side framework ?

Comment: Perhaps this link is useful: http://superuser.com/questions/425181/php-code-is-returned-instead-of-executed

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Querystring to get the search variable. But you are not sending anything.  So change your search.php to use POST or change the ajax method to send the query string...

```
$.ajax({
        url : "u.search.php?val=" + encodeURIComponent(elt),
        type: "GET",
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if (data.length) {
                $("div#search_results").html(data);
            }
            else $("div#search_results").html('<span class=\"no-result\">Enter your query</span>');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}
    });
```